# How do I combine two duplicate rows in a DataFrame which has different information or NaNs into a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below :

```
 Name           Email Assessment 1 Assessment 2 Assessment 3 Assessment 4    Assessment 5
0   abc   abc@email.com         Good          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
1   abc   abc@email.com          NaN        Good          Good          NaN          NaN   
2   abc   abc@email.com          NaN          NaN          NaN         Good          NaN   
3   abc   abc@email.com          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN         Good 
4  john  john@email.com         Good        Good          Fail          NaN          NaN   
5  john  john@email.com          NaN          NaN         Good          NaN          NaN
6  john  john@email.com          NaN          NaN          NaN         Good         Good   
7   joe   joe@email.com         Good        Good          Fail         Fail          NaN
8   joe   joe@email.com          NaN          NaN         Fail         Good         Good   
9   joe   joe@email.com          NaN          NaN         Fail          NaN          NaN
```

Here, I am trying to combine the duplicated records, using email as the key, and retaining the non-missing information from the following rows as the final information. In the above example, below is my expected output :

```
Name           Email Assessment 1 Assessment 2 Assessment 3 Assessment 4      Assessment 5
0   abc   abc@email.com         Good        Good          Good         Good         Good   
1  john  john@email.com         Good        Good          Good         Good         Good   
2   joe   joe@email.com         Good        Good          Fail         Good         Good
```

I have seen many solutions around combining of rows here but they mostly involve concatenation of the contents, i.e., they create a row value like `Good-Good-Good` or `Good-Good-Fail` for an email but not in the manner that I am expecting as shown in the sample output. Please help.

---

Sample Data

```
data_dict = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['abc','abc','abc','abc','john','john','john','joe','joe','joe'],
             'Email': ['abc@email.com','abc@email.com','abc@email.com','abc@email.com','john@email.com','john@email.com','john@email.com','joe@email.com','joe@email.com','joe@email.com'],
             'Assessment 1': ['Good', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Good', np.nan, np.nan, 'Good', np.nan, np.nan],
             'Assessment 2': [np.nan,'Good',np.nan,np.nan,'Good',np.nan,np.nan,'Good ',np.nan,np.nan],
             'Assessment 3': [np.nan,'Good',np.nan,np.nan,'Fail','Good',np.nan,'Fail','Fail','Fail'],
             'Assessment 4': [np.nan,np.nan,'Good',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Good','Fail','Good',np.nan],
             'Assessment 5': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Good',np.nan,np.nan,'Good','Fail','Good',np.nan]} )
```

Comment: What is logic if values per groups are `Fail-Good` or `Good-Fail` ?

Comment: In any case, the result in the latest row should prevail. `Fail - Good`, keeps `Good` as it occurs in the later row, and going by the same logic, `Good - Fail`, `Fail` will be the value in the combined row.

Comment: Ok, so then answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need last unique sorted without missing values per groups use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

def f(x):
    try:
        return np.sort(x.dropna().unique())[-1]
    except:
        return np.nan

df = df.groupby(['Name','Email'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(f)
print (df)
   Name           Email Assessment 1 Assessment 2 Assessment 3 Assessment 4  \
0   abc   abc@email.com         Good         Good         Good         Good   
1  john  john@email.com         Good         Good         Good         Good   
2   joe   joe@email.com         Good        Good          Fail         Good   

  Assessment 5  
0         Good  
1         Good  
2         Good
```

EDIT:

If need last non missing values use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','Email'], as_index=False, sort=False).last()
print (df)
   Name           Email Assessment 1 Assessment 2 Assessment 3 Assessment 4  \
0   abc   abc@email.com         Good         Good         Good         Good   
1  john  john@email.com         Good         Good         Good         Good   
2   joe   joe@email.com         Good        Good          Fail         Good   

  Assessment 5  
0         Good  
1         Good  
2         Good
```